# IntegrationTest with Mocha, stub HelperMethod (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing, ruby-mocha

I got a helper method:

> has_permission?

In a Module called:

> module ApplicationHelper

Inside app/helpers.

I also have an IntegrationTest which includes it:

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

My Integration test calls one of my controllers via get request.

On call I want to test if my integration test arrives at a certain method.

On this way is has to pass a few of the methods, one of those being the

> has_permission?

In order to make sure this method passes I wanted to stub it.

> Object.any_instance.expects(:has_permission?).returns(false) 
>   Doesn't work
>
> ApplicationHelper.expects(:has_permission?).returns(false)
>   Doesn't work either because it's not a static method.

Is there a way I can stub the helpers non-static method within the test so I can make it return false in all cases?

The test:

```
test "test try to edit without permission" do
@curr = users(:me)
sign_in @curr

SellingController.expects(:validate).never

post enable_update_user_selling_path(id: @user, params: {user: {sell: "1"}})
```

end

Comment: can you show your test case? Might be worth trying to stub it on the controller instance (`@controller`, if it's available)

Comment: I added the test, but unfortunately I don't have the @controller instance.

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across this when trying to work out how to stub an `ApplicationHelper` method in an `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` in Rails 5; not sure if that's exactly what you're trying to achieve but I ended up doing something like this

```
MyController.view_context_class.any_instance.expects(:my_method).returns(true)
```

It looks as though since Rails 5, helper methods aren't simply mixed into the controller classes directly hence the `view_context_class` bit.

Seems to work, hopefully this will be helpful to someone!

Comment: Thanks for responding, I forgot to post the solution I found a while ago already.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post how I ended up solving this:

`SellingController.any_instance.stubs(:has_permission?).returns(false)`